# How to make a user from LDAP an admin in KeyCloak V20.0.3?

Tags: docker, ldap, keycloak

We are running a working Keycloak in Docker setup with a Postgres database and we are able to synchronise our LDAP users.
Is it possible to make one of the LDAP users an admin? I can't find a role `realm-management` when I check the role mappings of a LDAP user.

We only want to use the default Keycloak admin as a backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user have to be federated in the ***Master*** realm, because this realm acts as a [parent / administrative realm](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#the-master-realm).
From there, it should have the `admin` role assigned.

Comment: This worked well. 
The only thing I had to to then was to mapping for the username from "cn" to sAMAccountName" to login with our 3-letter login instead of last name and name.
Thanks!